# Looking for HotFix to allow Windows Server 2003 to connect via SHA256 SSL

Tags: ssl, windows-server-2003, sha-2

This is a long shot. I am looking for a hotfix that allows Windows Server 2003 to connect to websites using SHA256 (SHA2) SSL.  I found several articles that reference it, but they all point to this page which gets a 404 error: [KB968730](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968730)

I searched extensively, but it seems to be nowhere to be found on the Microsoft site, or anywhere else that I can find.  Does anyone know where it can be found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a long shot. I am looking for a hotfix that allows Windows Server 2003 to connect to websites using SHA256 (SHA2) SSL. I found a number of articles that reference it, but they all point to this page which gets a 404 error: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968730

`KB968730` was replaced by `KB3072630` which is the reason you are unable to find `KB968730` anywhere.  `KB3072630` will automatically be installed through Windows Update

> I searched extensively but it seems to be nowhere to be found on the Microsoft site, or anywhere else that I can find. Does anyone know where it can be found, or if you have it, maybe post it somewhere for download?

[`KB3072630`](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3072630)is actually the patch you want.  This is confirmed by the fact the file version for [Crypt32.dll](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3072630/ms15-074-vulnerability-in-windows-installer-service-could-allow-elevat), is 5.131.3790.5668, which contains the necessary fix.

Source: [Enabling SHA2 Certificate Support on Windows Server 2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/606805/enabling-sha2-certificate-support-on-windows-server-2003)

Comment: Even if I had access to KB968730, it would be illegal, for me to provide a place to download it.  Additionally, there is no mechanism here at Stack Exchange to provide a file, to be downloaded.  So I have simply answered the question the best I can.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Hanging my head in shame for my search capabilities (or lack thereof).  I downloaded and applied KB3072630 as you suggested, but IE still cannot connect to any HTTPS site. I checked, and Crypt32.DLL is in fact now 5.131.3790.5668.  It can, however, connect to an HTTP site.

Comment: btw - I amended the question to not ask for someone to do something illegal.

Comment: Then you have not identified the real reason you cannot connect to HTTPS websites.  KB938397 brought the file to 5.131.3790.2951 while KB968730 brought the file to 5.131.3790.4477.  Since the patch in question I suggested brought the file version to 5.131.3790.5668 it contains the fixes in the previous patches.

Comment: I added a link to the Server Fault question in my answer, but if you follow the accepted answer to [KB2868626](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB2868626) it was actually replaced by KB3072630.  If the problem is due to the file in question either update should work.

Comment: Thank you! KB3072630 seemed to do the trick.  IE still cannot connect to an HTTPS site, but that appears to be a problem with IE.  My Client/Server app cannot use HTTPS SHA256 to connect!